# Web Crawler in Python for Yelp

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, mechanize-python

I have been trying to write a crawler for yelp. I want to get the links of the vendors provided on that page, I know it is given in a href=" but the array return is always empty, Please help! And thank you in advance :)

```
    import urllib
    import mechanize
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import re

    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.addheaders= [('User-agent', 'chrome')]

    BASE_URL = "http://www.yelp.com/"
    regex = "u(?!.*u).*,"
    patern =re.compile(regex)

    search = "house cleaner"
    location ="London, Uk"
    term = search.replace(" ","+")
    place = location.replace(",","%2C").replace(" ","+")
    query = BASE_URL+"search?find_desc="+term+"&find_loc="+place+"&ns=1#start=0"
    html = br.open(query).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    results = soup.findAll('ul',attrs={'class':'ylist ylist-bordered search-results'})
    results_parse = str(results)
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(results_parse)
    names =soup1.findAll("li")
    for li in names:
        soup2=BeautifulSoup(str(li))
        links=soup2.findAll("a")
        links_parse = links[0]
        vendor_links=[a["href"] for a in links]
        out= re.findall(patern,str(vendor_links))
        print out
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution to the **literal** problem of making your code do what you want it to (but please see below for why I don't think this is a good approach):

```
import requests                                                             
import lxml.html                                                            

BASE_URL = "http://www.yelp.com"                                            
search = "house cleaner"                                                    
location ="London, Uk"                                                      
term = search.replace(" ","+")                                              
place = location.replace(",","%2C").replace(" ","+")                        
query = BASE_URL + "/search?find_desc="+term+"&find_loc="+place+"&ns=1#start=0"

html = requests.get(query).content                                          
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
results = tree.xpath("//span[@class='indexed-biz-name']/a[@class='biz-name']/@href")

for result in results:                                                      
    print BASE_URL + result
```

Some pointers to why I've made various changes to your code if you're doing more scraping:

- mechanize is maybe a little too heavyweight to deal with a simple task like this (same goes for scrapy) when [requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/) exists and is a really easy to use library for making HTTP requests
- using XPath is really handy for pulling out specific features of web pages. You can see that this really simplifies the process of finding the elements that you want.

However, more generally, the first thing I would do if I was looking to pull information from a site is to **check if they have an API**.

[Yelp does](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation), and **I'd recommend you use that**. Why?

- **It's a contract of behaviour**; you can rely on anything documented in there. If there's some way of pulling out, e.g. links to business pages, it should stay stable. The same cannot be guaranteed for scraping their site: the layout of their site may change and the code here may well break.
- **It's an approved method for you to use to grab information.** If you have a valid API key, the only limit on Yelp API requests you make is [10,000 calls per day](http://www.yelp.com/developers/getting_started). On the other hand, if you're just scraping them as here, they may block your IP address to prevent it, especially if you're making large numbers of automated page requests.